# Android-App log in to website

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a question about how i can log in to my Website with my Android app.
I want to write an app referring to my website, so that I can log in and browse the new stuff in my app.

The website is written in PHP. Now I wonder how I can log in with username and password from my app. And also can I call GET or POST Methods etc. ?

Can you recommend any tutorial?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse yes you can use.

As you mentioned, website is written in PHP. make that response to encode in json. do some stuff in php side like collection of response in json. echo json_encode($response); in php for the login page and it displays json response.

Refer this tutorial.[Login with username and password](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)